# How can I connect my old Parachain to my new Relaychain?

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator

How can I connect my old Parachain to my new Relaychain?

The first thing I did is to recreate the chainspec using export-state: (9062 is my last block)

```
./target/release/my-parachain export-state \
--chain my-parachain-chainspec.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/collator1 9062 > my-parachain-chainspec-9062.json
```

The next step is to generate the genesis and wasm state from the new chainspec:

```
./target/release/my-parachain export-genesis-state \
--chain=my-parachain-chainspec-9062.json > para-genesis-state-9062
```

```
./target/release/my-parachain export-genesis-wasm \
--chain=my-parachain-chainspec-9062.json > para-genesis-wasm-9062
```

Then I register the parachain.  I still get an error:

```
2023-01-07 04:47:50 [Relaychain]  Idle (3 peers), best: #30793 (0x7974…5446), finalized #30790 (0xf1f9…19e1), ⬇ 1.4kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s
2023-01-07 04:47:52 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #9062 (0xf9b8…1087), finalized #9062 (0xf9b8…1087), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2023-01-07 04:47:54 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #30794 (0x0f21…f3fc)
2023-01-07 04:47:54 [Parachain] Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database! block_hash=0x922d43a0606e6c6315c301bcbd7c27ba5c8e88f9665e85b621796c82c81ce780
```

Ideas on how to restore old Parachain is highly appreciated.  This is a deal breaker for a Parachain, if we cannot restore data after the lease is terminated.

Comment: Can you edit you rQ and adding the script you are running your nodes with ?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what is rQ?

Comment: @hgminerva I think he means question*. "your Q"

Comment: yeah, I meant your question. Looks like I cannot edit my comment

Comment: So the steps you have followed so far are correct. Though I would like to know some extra info. Like the version of your nodes, if you are using warp sync. I assume the chain specs would be correct, but will be a plus if you could post the script you are using for launching your nodes, at least your collators.
I would be interested in seeing the launch scripts before and after the whole export, to check your db parameters.

Comment: Relay chain alice: ./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--chain rococo-local-cfd2.json \
--base-path /tmp/relay/validator1 \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944 \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--rpc-cors all \
--ws-external \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

Comment: Relay chain bob: ./target/release/polkadot \
--bob \
--chain rococo-local-cfd2.json \
--base-path /tmp/relay/validator2 \
--port 30334 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--rpc-cors all \
--ws-external

Comment: Colator: ./target/release/huminary-node \
--name Huminary \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain raw-huminary-chainspec-v2.json \
--base-path /tmp/huminary/collator1 \
--port 30335 \
--ws-port 9946 \
--rpc-external \
--rpc-methods Unsafe \
--rpc-cors all \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain rococo-local-cfd2.json \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977 \

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this won't work.

`export-state` will build a new chain spec upon the existing data.

The block number will start from 0. You can check the `state_root` and `parent_hash` in the new head data. They are totally different. And the log tells you, `Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database! block_hash=0x922d43a0606e6c6315c301bcbd7c27ba5c8e88f9665e85b621796c82c81ce780`.

---

I didn't try this before. But I guess you can get the current head data and wasm code on old relaychain and set them into the new relaychain. That's the correct data for your existing chain (I've tried this before to revert a parachain to an early state). But I'm not sure if this works for register parachain on a new relaychain.

Furthermore, you need to handle some states.

Like the HRMP data. If you have some HRMP data on the old relaychain but new parachain not, you can't produce block due to the mismatched state.

Check:

- https://twitter.com/AurevoirXavier/status/1633459851782389763
- https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/issues/308
- https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/pull/278
- https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/issues/289

Comment: Thank you, will check this out over the weekend

Answer (score 0):

From your instructions I can't spot where the problem is, your procedure seems correct.

But I can suggest you some resources to look at:

- Check this guide of how to perform a [Parachain State Rollback](https://hackmd.io/3BAy3HEzRVO2sBFnUaBVKA), you can follow the instructions to export the state (in your case omit the part of purge the data).
- Take a look on the answer in this previous SE question: [Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database!](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/could-not-find-the-header-of-the-genesis-block-in-the-database).
- Check this PR on the cumulus repo: [Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/385), it suggest the use of the optional flag `--parachain-id` to export the state.
- Take a look in the guide of how to [How to migrate from Kusama to Polkadot?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/how-to-migrate-from-kusama-to-polkadot)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll have a look